# Is the Colt Demonic?

Tags: supernatural

Prior to Ruby's tampering the colt had a bluish glow to it, and afterwards similar to Ruby's knife it's wounds glow red.

Has the Colt become demonic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The power to kill supernatural beings with The Colt seems to actually be focused on its bullets. It's possible (even likely) that a combination of the gun plus special ammo is needed for it to actually function, but a big deal was made about the ammunition that came with the gun. The color change is probably just due to Ruby's involvement in making the latest batch of ammo.

When the Winchesters first obtain the gun, it still has about half of its original 13 bullets that Samuel Colt made along with it. It's never specified, or even hinted, how he imbued the gun and those bullets with their power, apart from vague references to Haley's Comet. However, it seems logical that some existing supernatural force must have done it. (Its possible this was the source of it's inability to kill Lucifer -- whatever gave the gun its power may have been weaker than an archangel, but see below.)

Dean used the last of the original bullets to kill Azazel, after which the gun no longer worked to kill demons (or anything else a normal gun couldn't kill). That lasted until Ruby arrived and offered to "fix" the gun. Again, it's not clear exactly what she did to it, but it would have had to be one of:

- Alter the gun so that normal ammunition gained special powers, or
- Create additional special ammunition.

I haven't seen the episode in a while, but my impression was always that she did the latter. Either way, again, the power from the gun would have had to come from somewhere, and in this case we know that somewhere is Ruby. So the source of the gun's power has apparently changed from whatever blue-colored force it originally had, to the red-colored force that Ruby imbued it with. (It's also entirely possible that the gun's original power came from a demon, too, and Ruby just likes the color red better.)

It's not clear if the gun has lost any of its original potency -- in theory, the gun should now be unable to kill anything that Ruby herself lacked the power to kill. What this means in relation to Lucifer's statement that there are 5 things (himself included) that the gun cannot kill isn't clear. The list of things "stronger" than any demon, that were alive at the time, include all four archangels, Metatron, God himself (if you think he counts as "part of creation"), Death (if not all four horseman), and possibly Eve or the Leviathans, so the numbers are hard to add up. Lucifer could instead be speaking of the original gun+bullets, or be speaking in broader terms, but since we haven't seen the Colt in any episodes since he made that statement we may never know.

None of that, however, changes the basic nature of the gun, which is that it's an inanimate object with the capacity to kill *any* supernatural creature that is shot with a properly crafted bullet. It is possible that you could classify the gun or its bullets as *demonic* in the sense that the obtained their special properties from a demon, but the gun itself is neither good nor evil. As with all of the other weapons in the series, it is the user that determines the nature of the act

Comment: 4 archangels. Gabriel was still alive, hiding out as Loki. Raphael had already made an appearance (Castiel thought that he'd know where God was). Michael was in Heaven, vessel-less (soon to change), and Lucifer. Though, Lucifer never does confirm whether archangels are immune, or just him personally.

Comment: @John O - For some reason I thought that Gabriel has died already by the time Sam & Dean shot Lucifer but you're right that I had that backwards.

Comment: I truly hope he's still not dead. It wouldn't be difficult to bring him back. Maybe at the last second he discovered he couldn't kill his brother, and simply wanted Lucy locked back up... if he can make an illusion of himself, why not two? Raphael though... glad that piece of crap got water-ballooned.

Answer (score 4):

**No. The Colt is not necessarily a Demonic weapon. The pistol, considering its abilities, would seem to be, to use the roleplaying gaming parlance, considered True Neutral, since it can kill nearly any supernatural being of either good or evil persuasion. It will serve any master, good or evil and does not balk at killing either side.**

[image: The Colt and 13 rounds]

> The Colt is a hunter's legend; a singular gun made by Samuel Colt in 1835 for a hunter at the time. It has supernatural powers: when used with the supernatural bullets made specially for it, the gun can kill anything.
>
> It is said to be able to kill nearly any Supernatural being. Lucifer says he is one of only five things that can't be killed by it.
>
> It also acts as a key for the Devil's Gate in Wyoming, which opens a door to Hell. [**--Supernatural Wiki > The Colt**](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/index.php?title=The_Colt)

The description of The Colt does not define it as either good nor evil. How it achieves its powers is unknown. Considering the efficacy of its powers, it would have had to been imbued with its abilities by a Power; an Archangel, a major Demon at least as powerful as Crowley, Lucifer, or God, him/herself.

The Colt is a devastating weapon, apparently indestructible, and desired by both sides. The weapon, in its most ideal state, is best lost. Too long on one side or the other will only invite a catastrophic event as the weapon is hunted, found and eventually lost again.

Comment: Then what caused the colour change?

Comment: The person using it. Likely it was a special effect to show the device has been in the possession of one side or the other, red for demonic, blue for angelic or at least not directly demonic.

Comment: I would like to point out that rather than opening the door to Hell, Colt almost certainly designed the thing to *lock* the door to Hell. That a key meant to lock something up can also unlock it once more is an unfortunate and unintended side effect.

Answer (score 1):

What we do know about the Colt is rather limited. It will kill *anything* that doesn't belong to a list of 5 invulnerable entities. One of these is apparently Lucifer, but whether it is him specifically or archangels in general is left an open question.

It seems unlikely that it is demonic in nature. Created by Samuel Colt (a hunter himself) we actually see him use it to dispatch demons. While it is conceivable that their magic might be turned against him, we see nothing in the entire run of the series that suggests this is so. Besides, while other powerful artifacts of an evil nature make a routine appearance, they always bring misery and misfortune with them. The Colt is unique in that its presence always seems to be neutral, or even forebode good luck. (One possible exception, in season 1 the hunter who has it is unable to protect himself from vampires with its use. But it's difficult to blame the Colt for that.)

As for the special effects, I do believe that there are budgetary concerns in the later seasons. If you go back and watch the first time the Colt is used on the vampire, or even on Azazel, while they do make a big deal of it the effects are also nicer and edgier... we can almost see an X-ray effect on the creature, and lighting effects outside of its body (suggesting that the supernatural effect of the weapon exists outside of the slain, in the universe itself almost). While they probably didn't want to waste 15 seconds of screen time each time they kill a new monster with it, the post-production on that must have been expensive enough that they refused to use it once more. Farming out a cheaper effect to another team, minor details can change.

Finally, I think it's relevant to talk about the other superweapons that the show eventually reveals. While the Colt can't kill Lucifer, an archangel's sword can. We've also seen Death's scythe, and though never confirmed it is suggested (by Crowley, who rarely seems wrong when it is important to him) that it might kill Death itself. Additionally, there are other Heavenly weapons that seem to have *some* effect on beings like Raphael (Aaron's Staff, Lot's Salt, etc).

Compare this to Ruby's "hell-forged knife": it can only kill demons (or presumably other beings that could be killed by a regular knife). Death isn't instant or automatic either, if the stab wound is placed poorly or only minor, the demon does not die. If we can assume that the hell-forged knife is demonic in nature, then it would suggest that demonic weapons are pretty low down on the list of powerful artifacts.

My best guess is that while Samuel Colt may have simply stumbled across esoteric magic with which to make the gun, it is very likely that either God or Death helped him to fashion it, making it a divine weapon. Though unless they do more backstory, we'll probably never know.

Answer (score 1):

I think the bullets were made from melted angel blades. Remember when castile had the angel tablet and was traveling to different restaurants trying to escape the other angels? Crowley has an old German pistol with bullets made from a melted angel bkade, and when it hit an angel, it had the same effect as the colt, with the glowing and stuff. And an angel blade can kill demons and anything that's weaker or equal to an angel.